# redirection is not working after downloading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x-accel-redirect

Following is my show code in controller:

```
def show
  @archive = Archive.find(params[:id])
  if @archive.eula.blank? || params[:eula] == "1"
    send_archive(@archive) and return
    # redirect_to archives_url and return
  else
    @eula = @archive.eula
    render
  end
end

def send_archive(archive)
  head(:x_accel_redirect => archive.download.url, :content_type => archive.download.content_type, :content_disposition => "attachment; filename=#{archive.download.original_filename}")
end
```

For every download, i am displaying the Eula agreement to user `@eula = @archive.eula`. This eula has 2 buttons 'Accept' and 'decline'. If user clicks on 'decline', we simply return back to download page. If user click 'Accept', we will download the file for the user. But even after downloading the file, page does not return back to download page. Eula page is still displayed to user.
If i put `redirect_to archives_url and return` after `send_archive`, it throws an error:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action...

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can't send a HTTP 3xx redirect response and a file in the same response. If you want to redirect the user after they click the download button you will need to use javascript.

Comment: PS. you might want to use [`send_file`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file)

Comment: in simple you can't handle that on server side.

Comment: Is there anyway where when user clicks on 'accept' button, we redirect to download page and then download the file?

Comment: I have tried using `send_file archive.download.path
      \n redirect_to (archives_path)` but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I am new to ruby and finding it difficult to resolve this issue. Anyone has a sudo code for redirection after send_file method?

Answer (score 0):

Created a file '**eula.js**' at location: *app/assets/javascripts*
eula.js contains the following code:

```
    var interval = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction(){
        if(window.location.href === "http://www.yoursite.com")
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com";
        }
    }

    $('#Accept').click(function (event) {
        interval = setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In show.html.erb, you need to add `:id => "Accept"` so that js can recognize the button click. Now whenever user clicks on Accept, download will begin for him and after 5 sec of click, page will be redirected to your defined location. This piece of code is working fine for me.